# Docker: Building an image that depends on another image to be running

Tags: mysql, docker, alembic

**My objective is to build a Docker image that includes MySQL prefilled with the tables and data produced by an Alembic migration.** Unfortunately, Alembic can't produce the necessary data without an active MySQL instance, nor can it independently create a SQL dump to be [loaded by MySQL on first run](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mysql#initializing-a-fresh-instance).

I've attempted to use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to use both the `mysql` and `python` containers for this, but the MySQL daemon is brought down again as soon as the Python stage begins.

```
# start MySQL daemon
FROM mysql:5.6
RUN docker-entrypoint.sh

# install and run Alembic
FROM python:2.7-alpine
# [install Alembic]
COPY ./alembic-migrations /alembic-migrations
# [run migrations]
```

I'm not hung up on this particular solution, but it seemed like the simplest option. Is there a way to do what I'm attempting? Should I resign myself to installing Python and Alembic in the MySQL container?

Comment: Have you look into docker-compose?

Comment: We have a functional pipeline using `docker-compose` for this purpose, but it's slow because it needs to constantly re-run Alembic on every developer's machine, in every environment, every time someone switches branches. We want to build an image that can be distributed via a registry with all development/testing databases already baked in. If there's a way to do this with `docker-compose`, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll probably make some Docker evangelist's eyes bleed, but this is how I was able to accomplish the behaviour I was looking for. It was actually simpler and runs faster than I'd expected.

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine as python
FROM mysql:5.6

# set up a functional chroot of the Python image at /python
COPY --from=python / /python
RUN set -ex; \
    cp /etc/resolv.conf /python/etc/resolv.conf; \
    mknod -m 0644 /python/dev/random c 1 8; \
    mknod -m 0644 /python/dev/urandom c 1 9;

# install software depedencies in chroot jail
RUN set -ex; \
    chroot /python apk --no-cache --virtual add [some dependencies]

# install Python libraries
COPY ./requirements.txt /python/tmp/requirements.txt
RUN chroot /python pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt;

# apply Alembic migrations and remove the Python chroot jail
COPY ./usr/local/bin/build.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY ./alembic /python/alembic

RUN build.sh && rm -rf /python;

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh", "--datadir=/var/lib/mysql-persist"]

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

The `build.sh` script simply forks the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script from the MySQL container, then invokes the Alembic-specific code within the Python chroot.

```
#!/bin/sh
docker-entrypoint.sh --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-persist 2>/dev/null &

chroot /python build.sh
```

Note that I'm setting a custom data directory (`/var/lib/mysql-persist`) because the upstream mysql container defines `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql`, which I can't override.

The result is a built image that contains MySQL, complete with database, but does not contain any traces of the Python container or Alembic scripts. It can now be distributed via a registry and fetched by `docker-compose`, avoiding the need for all users to execute the Alembic migrations independently.